# line 1: This: command not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, command, npx

I have an issue. Whenever I try to run any npx command on my windows 11 system I get this error

C:\Users\JOEL MATHEW\node_modules.bin/../node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found

I have been facing this issue for a long time and it's still bothering me.

```
$ npx -v

9.5.0
 
$ npm -v

9.5.0

$ node -v

v18.14.2

$ npx create-react-app test

C:\Users\JOEL MATHEW\node_modules\.bin/../node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

[This image shows the error that is printed on my terminal after I run create-react-app .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUZqO.png)

Comment: still not working any other tips?

Answer (score 30):

I finally fixed my issue.

I received the error every time I ran the following
$ eas build -p android --profile preview
$ eas build -p android

**Steps to fix:**
Navigate to: C:\Users\USRN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node\bin\

On mine I found two node files, one that was a .exe and other other as just a text file

So I deleted the non executable file.

Hope this helps someone in future

Comment: Unbelievable. I upvoted this because this, of all the things I tried, actually fixed my problem as well. I could not grunt for the life of me. I tried uninstalling, reinstalling npx, npm, node, I tried installing different versions, etc, but nothing worked. Deleting this file fixed it. Hope this helps others.

Comment: it worked like a charm, thank you very much, Peter !!

Answer (score 0):

Check this to ensure npm npx installed:

```
npm --v
npx --v
```

Try this: (uninstall the create-react-app package)

```
npm uninstall create-react-app
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm cache clean --force
```

And then: (install create-react-app globally)

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

So then try again:

```
npx create-react-app my-app-name
```

Comment: i added the output in the post

Comment: check my edits, tell us what about

Comment: i ran the commands in my terminal but npx create-react-app my-app-name doesnt work but when i use create-react-app app-name it gives a different error

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix a similar problem recently through this thread. [Command not found - firebase login/firebase-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649789/command-not-found-firebase-login-firebase-tools?noredirect=1#comment135169146_76649789).

I am thinking it has something to do with your prefix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34685221)